# Why do I get no output from programs executed locally through PsExec?

Tags: windows, process, psexec

I am running `.\PsExec.exe \\$env:COMPUTERNAME ping www.google.com`

All I get is "ping exited with error code 0."

What do I need to do to actually view the output from ping?

I am running this through a Remote Desktop Console accessed via Bitvise SSH Server.

**EDIT**

The backstory here is that I am attempting to run a different program (not ping) through PsExec so that I can enable interactive features with -i, while running in a terminal that is stuck in Session 0.

Answer (score -1):

error code 0 is the flag that the command completed successfully, which you can test with

```
ping google.com 
echo %errorlevel%

ping google.coz
echo %errorlevel%
```

Which output 0 and then 1